# Magento 2 : Server specifications recommended for a given amount of products

Tags: magento2, performance, server-setup

Does magento 2 with more products require more processing power?
If yes what would be recommended specifications for a server hosting magento with around 400,000 simple products.

PS: I am asking this because it is taking too much time to reindex products.

> **Current Specs :**
>
> **CPU :** Xeon e3 1230v2 quad-core 4*3.7 GHz 
>    **RAM :** 32 Gb
>    **Storage :** 2TB

Comment: Please post your current configuration of server.

Comment: @Yogesh  Please check updated question